# Comparing check state of table items

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have setup a QStandardItemModel and populated it with data from another model which querys the database. The model is used in a table view where I display the information to the user. The first column is a 'check box' field which the user can check or uncheck. Below is the code I have used to setup the 'display' model (I have added comments to show where the checkbox is added)

```
 for ( int row = 0; row < m_infoModel->rowCount(); ++row )
        {
            QStandardItem *item;
            item = new QStandardItem;
            // Sets up checkbox here
            item->setData( QVariant ( Qt::Unchecked ), Qt::CheckStateRole );
            Qt::ItemFlags flags = ( Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled );
            item->setFlags( flags );
            m_displayModel->setItem( row, 0, item );
            // Checkbox setup complete...
            // ... More data added here
            item = new QStandardItem;
            item->setText( m_infoModel->data( m_infoModel->index( row, 0 ) ).toString() );
            m_displayModel->setItem( row, 1, item );
            item = new QStandardItem;
            item->setText( m_infoModel->data( m_infoModel->index( row, 1 ) ).toString() );
            m_displayModel->setItem( row, 2, item );
            item = new QStandardItem;
            item->setText( m_infoModel->data( m_infoModel->index( row, 2 ) ).toString() );
            m_displayModel->setItem( row, 3, item );
        }
```

After user interaction I iterate through each row in the table in order to check which rows have been checked so I can use the corresponding information.

```
    if ( m_infoModel->rowCount() != 0 )
    {
QStringList stringListOfVars;
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_displayModel->rowCount(); ++i )
                {
                    if ( m_displayModel->item( i, 0 )->checkState() == Qt::Checked )
                    {              
                        QString var = m_displayModel->data( m_displayModel->index( i, 2 ) ).toString(); 

                        stringListOfVars.prepend( var );
                    }
                }
    }
```

The problem and question I have is that the 'if' condition is always met even when there are checkboxes unchecked.

Comment: Why do you use `item->setData(QVariant(Qt::Unchecked), Qt::CheckStateRole);` and not `QStandardItem::setCheckState()` function? Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: Thanks @vahancho, I will try it out and let you know

Comment: Agree with @vahancho. You should do it in same way: `m_displayModel->item( i, 0 )->data( Qt::CheckStateRole ).toInt() == Qt::Checked`.

Comment: Worked! Can you add your comment as an answer so I can vote it up?